# Receive HTTP POST data for a database

Tags: linux, web-services, http-post

I'd like to know how to prepare a linux based server to receive Http Posts data. My idea is to receive data streams containing information to be stored after to a local database located in the same server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What programming language?  What web server? What database server? How large are the streams? etc.  We need more information about what you are trying to do in order to help.

Comment: It was an open question: I don't care as long as it is linux based (because previous experiences tough me not to trust windows...). I was thinking on using Apache; what I want to do is to receive text arrays containing small packages of data (no more than 1K every 15 minutes). Each time a packeage arrives, a script will read it and extract the data from it, in order to store it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

We use $_POST variable (rather than $_GET or $_REQUEST) to retrieve all HTTP POSTs data, however, if you looking for something else, you probably need to explain more...

Comment: You should specify what tool, program, service or library you're talking about. Not everybody uses PHP to listen to incoming HTTP requests.